# Find $y'$ if $y=e^{-4x} \sin\ 5x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $$y=e^{-4x} \sin\ 5x$$

My answer is: $y' = e^{-4x}(\cos\ 5x)(5)+(\sin\ 5x)e^{-4x}$ =

$$e^{-4x}((\cos\ 5x)(5)+(\sin\ 5x))$$

The books answer is different am I right?

Comment: You forgot the '-4' in the second term in your first step (chain rule).

Comment: $y'=-4e^{-4x}\sin(5x)+5e^{-4x}\cos(5x)$

Comment: Why do I need to find the derivative of the -4x? Can you explain? I thought $\frac{d}{dx}(e^x)=e^x$

Comment: @SunnyBlack, that's true. But that's just a special case of $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} e^{f(x)} = f'(x)e^{f(x)}$$ where $f(x) = x \implies f'(x) = 1$

Comment: @SunnyBlack Just like $(\sin5x)'=5\cos5x$, also $(e^{-4x})'=-4e^{-4x}$. Why one and not the other?

Comment: For first few steps your are correct but at the end for differentiating $e^{-4x}$ , you missed chain rule which is $e^{-4x}{-4} , you didn't write -4 as a coefficient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing a small part, you forgot the chain rule rule part.

$$y' = \sin 5x(e^{-4x})' + e^{-4x}(\sin 5x)' $$

Where $$(e^{-4x})' = (-4x)'e^{-4x} = -4e^{-4x}$$

So you get $$y' = 5e^{-4x}\cos 5x - 4e^{-4x}\sin 5x$$

Comment: I thought $\frac{d}{dx}(e^x)=e^x$

Comment: That's true, but $\frac{d}{dx} e^{f(x)} = f'(e)e^{f(x)}$

Answer (score 1):

As the given
$$y=e^{-4x}Sin5x$$
Differentiating w.r.t.x

by Product Rule i.e.
if $y=f(x).g(x)$

then $\frac{dy}{dx}=f(x).g^{'}(x)+f^{'}(x).g(x)$

So we have
$$y^{'}=e^{-4x}Cos5x(5)+e^{-4x}(-4)Sinx5x$$
$$y^{'}=5e^{-4x}Cos5x-4e^{-4x}Sinx5x$$
$$y^{'}=e^{-4x}(5Cos5x-4Sinx5x)$$

The determinant of exponentiale is
$e^x = e^x.dx$ or

if

$$y=e^{ax}$$
Then by diff w.r.t.x
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{ax}.\frac{d}{dx}(ax)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{ax}.\frac{dx}{dx}a$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{ax}a$$
so if we diff exponential then we also further diff its power